# Filename with characters %%%%%%%

Tags: laravel

Hi I just bought a filesharing Laravel but after uploading the file name it's not like: `Bla Bla - Bla Bla Bla` it's with `%% Bla%Bla%-Bla%bla` and looking very bad.

I checked but as I'm new with Laravel I don't really know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use space in your file name.

Please rename your file to Bla-Bla-Bla-Bla

Comment: The thing is I just need to have the name of file with space between words not with special characters.

Comment: This is url encoding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. The recommendation to not use spaces in filenames

Comment: Ok I'm talking about filename like when file is 100% uploaded on download page you have FileName: bla+bla+bla all I need to have the name with space between words not that +++

Comment: Sorry but I think it is not possible in web platform application. you can create a mini program or script and rename all file and replace spaces into '_' or '-'